# Which architecture for Windows 10 UWP

Tags: uwp

I'm creating a Windows UWP app that is specifically targeted at Windows 10 mobile devices. It looks to me like the only architecture used by these devices is ARM, but when I come to select and configure the packages in Visual Studio it offers me x86, x64 and ARM options.

If I only select ARM, VS won't let me run the Windows App Certification on my local machine, forcing me to add one of the other options as well.

What options should I be selecting if I only want to release for Windows 10 Mobile?

Supplementary question - Is it possible to release for Windows 10 Phone only and not tablets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows App Certification Kit runs the tests on the application on your local machine which won't support the ARM (Phone) variant of your application. This is why it will be asking for another option. It would be best to build all configurations regardless of whether you want to submit for phone only.

With regards to your other question, yes. You can make this decision in the Windows Store submission process when you've uploaded your app package.

[image: Windows Store Submission]

Here you can see you have the option to 'Let Microsoft decide...'. For your scenario, you may want to uncheck that. Also, as you can see, you can select the platforms you want to publish to and in your scenario you would only select Windows 10 Mobile.